# Cross-origin Cookies on Safari

Tags: ios, macos, safari, session-cookies

While investigating the (just released) Chrome 80 cookie changes (required SameSite=None for cross-domain cookies), I noticed some strange behavior in one of my applications. The particular application is embedded in another site - the the content is located in www.domain1.com, but the embedded application authenticated and loads from www.domain2.com. We use cookie-based authentication at the moment.

Because of the Chrome 80 cookie changes, we ended up adding SameSite=None to our cookies so that they could be used to authenticate and transfer to www.domain2.com when we made requests via our API. This fixed the Chrome 80 bug we were anticipating, but we discovered that Safari would not work in either iOS (versions 12 and 13 were tested) or Mac OS (versions 10.15 and 10.15). We narrowed the issue down to a default setting in iOS and Mac OS - the "Prevent cross-site tracking" checkbox in Safari preferences. Whenever that box is checked, our cookies do not transfer from domain1 to domain to, even when SameSite=None is set. This seems like it could potentially cause issues for a lot of different platforms, as prior to recently most sites expected cookies to be able to transfer this way.

Is this intentional behavior, or do we have something set up wrong? I've read about other applications having this problem, but have not found any solutions other than hacks like redirecting to a page on domain2 prior to loading the content on domain1, which isn't really an option for us. Is there some way to get around this, or a way to correct our setup so that we can actually pass cookies as we need?

Here's an example cookie that we receive back from our API during authentication:

```
"thirdPartyBlocked=1; expires=Tue, 09-Feb-2020 01:59:04 GMT; path=/{our app path}/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none"
```

This cookie works and transfers as expected in every browser other than Safari. Any ways to fix this issue?

Comment: I am not sure but i think i have read somewhere that older versions safari don't interpret Cookie with "SameSite=none" and treat them as "SameSite=strict".

Comment: facing the same issue on safari 15.x
would appreciate if there is a fix or an update regarding this